# Import automatically input file in Drive in web app

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm having a problem ro import automatically the file selected in the input on the Drive.
I've followed several articles on this site and others, but I can't find my error.

This is  my simplified code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="idInput" onchange="test(idInput)">
  </body>

  <script>
  function test(photo){
    var file = document.getElementById(photo.id).files[0];
    console.log("file content :");
    console.log(file);
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e){
      const obj = {
        filename: file.name,
        mimeType: file.type,
        bytes: [...new Int8Array(e.target.result)]
      };
      console.log("obj content :");
      console.log(obj);
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().uploadFiles(obj);
    };
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }

  </script>
</html>


function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Index");
}

function uploadFiles(data) {
const myFile = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data.data),data.mimeType,"test");
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1yYgC7KCdmVLYjvHutCDqHyKGnevc64rr");
folder.createFile(myFile);
}
```

When I try to import a picture, this is why i obtain in my console :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dbae.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXT08.png)

I see that the problem is in this line :
`const myFile = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data.data),data.mimeType,"test");`

I think my problem is with the bytes part but i'm not sure.

Thank you for advance for your help

I tried others types of code but I've the same problem...

Comment: Can you provide the full error message in text format?

Comment: Of course → Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property newBlob on object Utilities at uploadFiles(Code:6:30)

Comment: That's only the first line of the error. There is a triangle in your screenshot and if you click on that triangle, then further details of the error will be opened.

Comment: oh sorry, i edited my question, you can find detail here. But i don't understand anything what is writted

Comment: Can you provide your whole script of `uploadFiles`? Because, although, in your Javascript, the file content is converted to int8Array as the property of `bytes` with `bytes: [...new Int8Array(e.target.result)]`, in your Google Apps Script, the property of `data` with `data.data` is used. And, that is used as the base64 data. But I have no information about `data`. I apologize for this. So, I think that it is required to confirm your Google Apps Script side.